# netty client can only receive one reponse from server

Tags: java, netty

Recently，I use netty 4 write a client and server，client send five message to server，but client can only receive one response from server，here is my codes.

DTO:RpcRequest

```
package com.huawei.simple.rpc.base.request.dto;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

import java.lang.reflect.Parameter;

@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class RpcRequest {
    private String requestId;
    private String interfaceName;
    private String methodName;
}
```

DTO:RpcResponse

```
package com.huawei.simple.rpc.base.response.dto;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class RpcResponse {
    private String requestId;
    private String responseMessage;
    private int responseCode;
    private Object responseBody;
}
```

Codec

```
public class ResponseDecoder extends ByteToMessageDecoder {
    private static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    @Override
    protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext channelHandlerContext, ByteBuf byteBuf, List<Object> list) throws Exception {
        if (byteBuf.readableBytes() < 4) {
            return;
        }
        byteBuf.markReaderIndex();
        int dataLength = byteBuf.readInt();
        if (byteBuf.readableBytes() < dataLength) {
            byteBuf.resetReaderIndex();
            return;
        }
        byte[] data = new byte[dataLength];
        byteBuf.readBytes(data);
        RpcResponse response = mapper.readValue(data, RpcResponse.class);
        list.add(response);
    }
}
public class ResponseEncoder extends MessageToByteEncoder<RpcResponse> {
    private static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    @Override
    protected void encode(ChannelHandlerContext channelHandlerContext, RpcResponse rpcResponse, ByteBuf byteBuf) throws Exception {
        byte[] bytes = mapper.writeValueAsBytes(rpcResponse);
        int dataLength = bytes.length;
        byteBuf.writeInt(dataLength);
        byteBuf.writeBytes(bytes);
        byteBuf.writeBytes(SerializationUtil.serialize(rpcResponse));

    }
}
public class RequestDecoder extends ByteToMessageDecoder {
    private static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext channelHandlerContext, ByteBuf byteBuf, List<Object> list) throws Exception {
        if (byteBuf.readableBytes() < 4) {
            return;
        }
        byteBuf.markReaderIndex();
        int dataLength = byteBuf.readInt();
        if (byteBuf.readableBytes() < dataLength) {
            byteBuf.resetReaderIndex();
            return;
        }
        byte[] data = new byte[dataLength];
        byteBuf.readBytes(data);
        RpcRequest request = mapper.readValue(data, RpcRequest.class);
        list.add(request);
    }
}
public class RequestEncoder extends MessageToByteEncoder<RpcRequest> {
    private static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    @Override
    protected void encode(ChannelHandlerContext channelHandlerContext, RpcRequest rpcRequest, ByteBuf byteBuf) throws Exception {
        byte[] bytes = mapper.writeValueAsBytes(rpcRequest);
        int dataLength = bytes.length;
        byteBuf.writeInt(dataLength);
        byteBuf.writeBytes(bytes);
    }
}
```

Client

```
public class RpcClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        RpcClient server = new RpcClient();
        server.build();
    }

    public void build() {
        NioEventLoopGroup boss = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        Bootstrap s = new Bootstrap();
        s.group(boss).channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
            .option(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY,true)
            .handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                @Override
                protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws Exception {
                    socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(new RequestEncoder());
                    socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(new ResponseDecoder());
                    socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(new RpcClientHandler());
                }
            });
        try {
            ChannelFuture future = s.connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost",8080)).sync();
            future.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            boss.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }
}
public class RpcClientHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
    private static AtomicInteger id = new AtomicInteger(1);

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            RpcRequest request = new RpcRequest();
            request.setRequestId(id.getAndIncrement() + "");
            request.setMethodName("helloWorld");
            request.setInterfaceName("interface");
            ChannelFuture future = ctx.writeAndFlush(request);
            future.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
                @Override
                public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture channelFuture) throws Exception {
                    if (channelFuture.isSuccess()) {
                        System.out.println("Success");
                    }
                }
            });
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        super.channelInactive(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        RpcResponse response = (RpcResponse) msg;
        System.out.println("get reponse from server " + response.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        super.channelReadComplete(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
        super.exceptionCaught(ctx, cause);
    }
}
```

Server

```
public class RpcServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        RpcServer server = new RpcServer();
        server.build();
    }

    public void build() {
        NioEventLoopGroup boss = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        NioEventLoopGroup worker = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        ServerBootstrap s = new ServerBootstrap();
        s.group(boss, worker).channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
            .option(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true)
            .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 10)
            .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.DEBUG))
            .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                @Override
                protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws Exception {
                    socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(new RequestDecoder());
                    socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(new ResponseEncoder());
                    socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(new RpcServerHandler());
                }
            });
        try {
            ChannelFuture future = s.bind(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 8080)).sync();
            future.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            boss.shutdownGracefully();
            worker.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }
}
public class RpcServerHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        RpcRequest request = (RpcRequest) msg;
        System.out.println("get request from client " + request.toString());
        RpcResponse response = new RpcResponse();
        response.setRequestId(request.getRequestId());
        ChannelFuture future = ctx.writeAndFlush(response);
        future.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
            @Override
            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture channelFuture) throws Exception {
                if (channelFuture.isDone()) {
                    System.out.println("Done");
                } else if (channelFuture.isSuccess()) {
                    System.out.println("Success");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        super.channelReadComplete(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
        super.exceptionCaught(ctx, cause);
    }
}
```

The output is
Server:

1. get request from client RpcRequest(requestId=1, interfaceName=interface, methodName=helloWorld)
   Done
2. get request from client RpcRequest(requestId=2, interfaceName=interface, methodName=helloWorld)
   Done
3. get request from client RpcRequest(requestId=3, interfaceName=interface, methodName=helloWorld)
   Done
4. get request from client RpcRequest(requestId=4, interfaceName=interface, methodName=helloWorld)
   Done
5. get request from client RpcRequest(requestId=5, interfaceName=interface, methodName=helloWorld)
   Done

Client

1. Success
2. Success
3. Success
4. Success
5. Success
6. get reponse from server RpcResponse(requestId=1,
   responseMessage=null, responseCode=0, responseBody=null)

Why my client get only one response from server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either have made an error inside `ResponseEncoder` or inside `ResponseDecoder` (I'm guessing the first one.

> ```
> public class ResponseDecoder extends ByteToMessageDecoder {
>     private static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
>     @Override
>     protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext channelHandlerContext, ByteBuf byteBuf, List<Object> list) throws Exception {
>         if (byteBuf.readableBytes() < 4) {
>             return;
>         }
>         byteBuf.markReaderIndex();
>         int dataLength = byteBuf.readInt();
>         if (byteBuf.readableBytes() < dataLength) {
>             byteBuf.resetReaderIndex();
>             return;
>         }
>         byte[] data = new byte[dataLength];
>         byteBuf.readBytes(data);
>         RpcResponse response = mapper.readValue(data, RpcResponse.class);
>         list.add(response);
>     }
> }
> public class ResponseEncoder extends MessageToByteEncoder<RpcResponse> {
>     private static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
>     @Override
>     protected void encode(ChannelHandlerContext channelHandlerContext, RpcResponse rpcResponse, ByteBuf byteBuf) throws Exception {
>         byte[] bytes = mapper.writeValueAsBytes(rpcResponse);
>         int dataLength = bytes.length;
>         byteBuf.writeInt(dataLength);
>         byteBuf.writeBytes(bytes);
>         byteBuf.writeBytes(SerializationUtil.serialize(rpcResponse));
>
>     }
> }
> ```

Your encoder writes a Response as:

```
int: length of bytes
bytes: The result of the mapper
serialize: the result of the serialize operation
```

But those are read inside the decoder as:

```
int: length of bytes
bytes: The result of the mapper
```

You either forgot to handle the extra bytes in the decoder, or send to much data.

This causes the appearance of the program not reading, as client is actually waiting for more data, as I am assuming the data of "serialize" does not start with a zero, causing unusually high values for the length inside the decoder.

Comment: Thank you very much，you are right. I serialize the response body two times,so only one can deserialized.